# Duplicate in exception handling

Tags: java, exception, refactoring

I have two APIs (say `create` and `update`) that calls the same `serviceA`. `serviceA` has a conditional block that will only be called in case of `update`. `serviceA` throws a number of different exceptions but some of them will only be thrown within the conditional block called by `update` I am looking for suggestions for exception handling in my APIs (`create` and `update`). What is a recommended practice here? I don't want to have duplicate exception handling logic but if I extract the error handling logic, I might have to catch exceptions that are only applicable to `update` for `create` as well.

```
public class ServiceA {
    void upsert(Request request) {
    //some common operations for create and update
    if (request.action == "UPDATE") {
        //update
        if (someUpdateErrorCondition) {
            throw new ExceptionA();
        } elseif (someOtherUpdateErrorCondition) {
            throw new ExceptionB();
        }
        ...
    }
    if (someErrorCondition) {
        throw new ExceptionC();
    } elseif (someOtherErrorCondition) {
        throw new ExceptionD();
    }
    ...
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Provide some code, please!

Comment: What you describe is one of the (many) reasons why I don't think it is at all a good idea to call serviceA and then have serviceA test some kind of flag to determine whether it is doing create or update. Why not have create and update use different services; if those different services have a block of logic that they both need, they call it; I think this is preferable by far than having create and update in one block of logic with tests to determine which blocks of logic to execute. And it solves your problem, they can create and declare only those exceptions they need.

Comment: @arcy I agree with you on separating create and update in serviceA but I feel like the duplicate in exception handling persists as `create` and `update` api still have common exceptions to handle. How can I avoid that duplication?

Comment: I don't know how to answer this in the abstract. We would have to get down to specifics. I'm willing to do that, though an SO question's comments are not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I correctly understood the problem, but if you have common exceptions to handle as well as specific exceptions then you could use a lambda for common error handling.
 There's various flavors of the same approach which is to control the execution with a shared component, whether you use function composition, the decorator pattern, etc.

E.g. (non-java pseudo-code)

```
function process1() {
  withCommonErrorHandling(() => {
    try { 
        //could throw CommonError or Process1Error
    } catch (Process1Error e) {
        //handle
    }

  });
}

function process2() {
  withCommonErrorHandling(() => {
    try { 
        //could throw CommonError or Process2Error

    } catch (Process2Error e) {
        //handle
    }

  });
}

function withCommonErrorHandling(fn) {
  try { fn() }
  catch (CommonError e) {
      //handle
  }
}
```